# I am facing problem in pushing my service data to the Array in ANGULAR

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, multidimensional-array, angular5

I am trying to push Images which is coming from service to an Array , and using that Array I am trying to slide Images in my Application  .

### I am putting the MY component FILE below

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
head_slider: any = [];
imgslider: any = [];

  constructor( public http: HttpClient ) { }

  slides  = [  ];

slideConfig  = {'slidesToShow': 4, 'slidesToScroll': 4};

  ngOnInit() {

  this.http.get('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&apiKey=69e4c9820959482e8c40e42f8bcfe975').subscribe(data => {
    this.head_slider = data['articles'];

   console.log(this.head_slider);
   this.slides.push( 'img :' + this.head_slider.urlToImage);
  });

  }

addSlide() {
  this.slides.push({img: 'http://placehold.it/350x150/777777'});
}

removeSlide() {
  this.slides.length = this.slides.length - 1;
}

afterChange(e) {
  console.log('afterChange');
}

}
```

> In the above code I want to push the  key and value which is images exists in  the service to the Array
>   **slides  = [  ]; ,  In this way --- >     slides  = [ img: , img: , img:   ];**

### I am putting html file below

```
<ngx-slick class="carousel" #slickModal="slick-modal" [config]="slideConfig" (afterChange)="afterChange($event)">
        <div ngxSlickItem *ngFor="let slide of slides" class="slide">
              <img src="{{ slide.img }}" alt="" width="100%">
        </div>
    </ngx-slick>

    <button (click)="addSlide()">Add</button>
    <button (click)="removeSlide()">Remove</button>
    <button (click)="slickModal.slickGoTo(2)">slickGoto 2</button>
    <button (click)="slickModal.unslick()">unslick</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate through `head_slider` because it is an array.

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.http.get('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&apiKey=<<api key here>>').subscribe(data => {
        this.head_slider = data['articles'];
        for(let i = 0; i < data['articles'].length; i++){
            this.slides.push({img: data['articles'][i].urlToImage})
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: But using your code when I write , console.log(this.slides[0]);  I am getting result as   {img: undefined}

Comment: It works thanks alto ! can you help me in Auto Increment of the Image slider .

Answer (score 0):

Please change

```
this.slides.push( this.img = this.head_slider.urlToImage)
```

to

```
this.slides.push( {img: this.head_slider.urlToImage});
```